# How to get an IP un-blocked from the MTA spam lists !

Tags: ip, spam

We are trying to shift our corporate email server from our ISP to the rackspace cloud.
Looks like who ever used the IP (that my virtual server was assigned) before
has abused it for sending a lot of spam.
Now none of the major free email providers - gmail,yahoo, hotmail etc are accepting
mails from this IP as it is on their block list.

Any suggestions for getting that IP address off that list as we now want to use it
for legit mail server.

thanks
Pari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you will get it off the lists is to contact the Blacklist providers and get them to remove it. Which for some providers is quite straightforward, others not so much.

If this IP was allocated to you by Rackspace recently I would probabley go back to them and get them to give you another IP, rather than having to go to all these providers your self.

Comment: I agree, much easier to get a new IP

Answer (score 2):

Your IP is presumably listed in one ore more [RBL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL#Terminology). You have to manually ask the major RBL to remove your IP from their lists.

You can look at **`http://www.robtex.com/ip/<YOUR_IP>.html#blacklists`**, for example, to know in which Black List your IP is, then follow the RBL instructions to be removed.

Comment: thanks for answering albert, unfortunately i can only pick one for the answer, so this time i am going with sam, may be next time.